# Will a database generated from SQL Server Express work with the main version of SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I want to create a SQL Server Express database on my local machine and then upload it to a website that will be using the full SQL Server software - can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can.  You have a few options:

1. Backup and restore
2. Script everything manually
3. Database publishing wizard

Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en

Comment: The other option is to detach from Express and attach on SQL Server (which is IMHO the simplest solution).  Watch out for user accounts when doing this though.

Answer (score 2):

The MS SQL Express databases are completely compatible with full versions of MS SQL Server. So just backup and restore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are designed to be compatible.  You can either script out of the database or use the Backup/Restore functionality built into SQL Server Management Studio.  More details on the latter can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/MgSQLExpwSSMSE.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can move from SQL Express to the full SQL Server quite easily. There's a couple of ways to go about doing this, but the easiest is to back up the databases in question on SQL Express, install the full version of SQL Server, and restore the databases there. Both programs use the same database backup format. However both instances of SQL Server should be configured with the same collation.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to buy [SQL Server Developer edition.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001B8EZR4)  It's quite cheap and will install on a desktop O/S such as Windows XP.  The main advantage over SQL Server Express is that it has all of the features of Enterprise Edition (CLR sprocs, SSIS etc.) and you can develop with this functionality.  YMMV as you may or may not need these features.